# Swagger/OpenAPI documentation for file upload endpoint with metadata

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-gin

I have a POST endpoint in Golang Gin that allows users to upload a file and a json object as metadata that I will store. I also use https://github.com/swaggo/swag to generate swagger/OpenApi documentation by annotating my code.

My problem is I can't find the documentation (neither on swagger site nor in swaggo) on how to add metadata as a param in OpenApi.

This is the curl command that I use to upload the file and metadata:

```bash
curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost:9090/datafile' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F 'file=@README.md' \
-F 'metadata={
    "key1": 123,
    "key2": "value",
    "name": "my-readme"
  }'
```

Comment: `// @Param file formData file true "upload file"
// @Param metadata formData string true "metadata"
// @Accept      mpfd`. [doc](https://github.com/swaggo/swag#param-type)

Comment: @Trock so I can't enforce a structure to the json in the metadata? In my other endpoints, I just pass the type and it properly shows it in the OpenApi with all the fields that are required.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you would use the [Encoding](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#encoding-object) object

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: an api
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://api.thing.com/api
paths:
  /thing:
    post:
      summary: a request body with encoding defined per the OAS specification
      requestBody:
        description: a multpart request body with an encoding object
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                metadata:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    key1:
                      type: string
                    key2:
                      type: number
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
            encoding:
              metadata:
                contentType: application/json
              file:
                headers:
                  content-disposition:
                    $ref: '#/components/headers/content-disposition'
                contentType: application/octet-stream
      responses: 
        '201':
          description: Created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: 
                type: string
components:
  headers:
    content-disposition:
      description: Describes the file name of an entity-body
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
```

SwaggerUI doesn't seem to display the `metadata` object correctly.

[image: swaggerui]

---

You can see a representation of it with [Redoc](https://redocly.github.io/redoc)

[image: redoc]

---

Unfortunately, both of these web based editors don't display the `headers` defined within the `encoding` object. I'm not sure of any implementations who are fully compliant with this part of the specification.